# Swift How to get from a phrase a dictionary with number of characters

Tags: arrays, string, swift, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionnary from a string with the word and the number of caracter of each word.

```
var textToShow:String = "Try not to become a man of success, but" //rather try to become a man of value. Albert Einstein"

    print(charactersCount(textToShow))

func charactersCount(s: String) -> Dictionary<String, Int> {
    var words = s.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    var characterInWordDictionary = Dictionary<String, Int>()

    for word in words {
            characterInWordDictionary[word] = word.characters.count
    }
    return characterInWordDictionary
}
```

The problem is, with this methode, it return

```
 ["Try": 3, "not": 3, "a": 1, "become": 6, "of": 2, "but": 3, "man": 3, "to": 2, "success,": 8]
```

It is not so bad, but:
- first, the dictionary is not in the right order
- second, i would like also the space in the dictionary.

What I would like to return is:

```
["Try": 3, " ": 1, "not": 3, " ": 1, "to": 2, " ": 1, "become": 6, " ": 1, "a": 1, " ": 1, "man": 3, " ": 1, "of": 2, " ": 1, "success,": 8, " ": 1, "but": 3]
```

If anyone can provide any guidance on this, that would be amazing.

Tks,

Comment: A dictionary has no order. You need an array of tuples

Comment: Dictionaries are non-ordered collections, so what you're looking for is possibly rather an array of tuples `(String, Int)` rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an empty tupleArray. Next break up your sentence using componentsSeparatedByString and iterate through all elements (words) using forEach to append that element ($0 = word) and its characters count followed by a tuple of (" ",1). Then just use popLast to delete that extra tuple. Try like this:

```
let textToShow = "Try not to become a man of success, but"

var tupleArray:[(String, Int)] = []

textToShow.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
          .forEach{tupleArray += [($0,$0.characters.count),(" ",1)]}
tupleArray.popLast()
print(tupleArray.description)  // "[("Try", 3), (" ", 1), ("not", 3), (" ", 1), ("to", 2), (" ", 1), ("become", 6), (" ", 1), ("a", 1), (" ", 1), ("man", 3), (" ", 1), ("of", 2), (" ", 1), ("success,", 8), (" ", 1), ("but", 3)]\n"
```

Comment: The problem with this, is that the space between words may not always be of length 1. Also, what if it does end with space? Or if it does begin with space. It does not deal with all the cases.

Comment: @MateHegedus those cases the string it is not properly formatted

Comment: @MateHegedus Don't you know how to format a sentence? Just look at OP code

Comment: If we're looking at sentences then it works fine. But the OP does not say we are working with legal sentences. Just that we have strings.

Comment: All he asked was to keep it in order and to add the spaces in between

Comment: No, he also asked to "second, i would like also the space in the dictionary"

Comment: Sometimes, there could be more than one space. Sometimes, there could be a space at the end too.

Comment: Where in the question OP stated that ? he is splitting his sentence using  `var words = s.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")`

Comment: He never said he uses valid sentences. Only that he uses strings. That's why I think a good solution needs to handle all cases.

Comment: I am talking about down voting this answer without a reason. The question it is about keeping the sentence order and also the spaces between the words. Who needs extra spaces between words or a sentence starting with a space?

Comment: Hello guys. Thank you for your interventions and I'm sorry that I didn't specify this aspect. Leo supposed correctly. I don't want more than one space between words. Actually, i founded a string extension to remove all excessive spaces. But, I must to confess that the solution of Mate is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little function for you that does this:

```
var textToShow:String = "Try not to become a man of success, but" // rather try to become a man of value. Albert Einstein"



func charactersCount(s: String) -> [(String, Int)] {
    var result = [(String, Int)]()

    var word = String(s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(0)])
    var size = 1

    var space = s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(0)] == " "

    for (var i:Int = 1; i < s.characters.count; i++) {
        if (s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)] == " ") {
            if (space) {
                size++
                word.append(s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)])
            } else {
                result.append((word, size))
                size = 1
                space = true
                word = " "
            }
        } else {
            if (space) {
                result.append((word, size))
                size = 1
                space = false
                word = String(s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)])
            } else {
                size++
                word.append(s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)])
            }
        }
    }
    result.append((word, size))

    return result
}

print(charactersCount(textToShow))
```

The output is:

```
["Try": 3, " ": 1, "not": 3, " ": 1, "to": 2, " ": 1, "become": 6, " ": 1, "a": 1, " ": 1, "man": 3, " ": 1, "of": 2, " ": 1, "success,": 8, " ": 1, "but": 3]
```